# JS if( item === ? ) statement not firing. Comparing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Purpose:**
User inputs information. Script goes and checks if `appendJSON.json` has anything in its contents. Either returns the contents of `.json` or `[]`.

**Problem:**
When comparing `findNote === ''`the `if` statment doesn't not fire off `return []`.
If there is something in `appendJSON.json` the `else` statment fires off like intented `return findnote`.

**Attempts:**
Tried comparing `findNote` to `''`, `null` and `undefiend`. Same outcome, what was returned was nothing.

**1st Code-block:** that accepts input then checks `.json` for any contents. 
`log` to see what is coming back from `fetchNotes()`

```
function addNote(argv) {
  const newSubmission = argv;
  const getLibrary = fetchNotes().toString();
  log(getLibrary);
}
```

**2nd Code-block:** `fetchNotes()`:

```
function fetchNotes() {
  const findNote = fs.readFileSync("./appendJSON.json");
  if (findNote === "") {
    return [];
  } else {
    return findNote;
  }
}
```

I've tried slightly refactoring the code to remove the `else` statment:

```
function fetchNotes() {
  const findNote = fs.readFileSync("./appendJSON.json");
  if (findNote === "") {
    return [];
  }
  return findNote;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to log `findNote`? What's it output? Don't use fs' sync functions

Comment: I can only conclude that `findNote` is not an empty string. No idea what it actually is, though - it might be a single space, or a newline or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're not providing the `encoding` option, [`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) returns a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer), not a string. A `Buffer` will never be `===` to `''`. You probably wanted:

```
const findNote = fs.readFileSync('./appendJSON.json', 'utf8');
```

...but that assumes the contents are UTF-8, not (say) Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1. Be sure you don't assume incorrectly, as you'll get corrupted characters for characters outside the ASCII range...

---

Side note: It seems quite odd to return an empty array if the file is empty, but a `Buffer` or string if it isn't.

Comment: I'm taking a Udemy course and for now we are using `readFileSync`. Simply entering a book submission into the console using `yargs`

`node index.js add --title='a title' --author='someone' --body='somebody'`

The script takes that input, then goes and looks in `.json` to see if there is already a `[]`, if so it returns the array, if not it's SUPPOSE to return a blank `[]`.
**side note** the `.json` file is blank. So I expect the script to place `[]` inside & return it

A knowledge gap of mine is understanding when `''`,`null` or `undefined` should be used in comparisons